# Windows Phone 8 find out IMEI / device name + manufacturer

Tags: windows-phone-8, imei

I need to find out on which Windows phone device my app is running. Is there a reliable way to find out the IMEI in WP8? If not, is the DeviceName and DeviceManufacturer field reliably filled in by most devices? The documentation says those fields may be empty.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Unique ID of Windows Phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470804/how-to-get-unique-id-of-windows-phone)

Comment: The WP7 solution to the question listed above indeed also works on WP8.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
//Device Name
Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus.DeviceName

//Device Unique Identifier (not IMEI)
Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceUniqueId")))

//Device Manufacturer
Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus.DeviceManufacturer
```

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

This may work on Windows Phone 7. Maybe, it will also work on Windows Phone 8.

```
byte[] byteData = (byte[])DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue(“DeviceUniqueId”);
string imei = System.Convert.ToBase64String(byteData);
```

Comment: This is not going to be the IMEI

Comment: This is not IMEI, Its Just Unique Identifier of Device

Answer (score 0):

DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue(“DeviceUniqueId”) works as stated on Windows Phone 7 but on Windows Phone 8, this API will return unique id common across all the apps for the same publisher on a wp8 device. But two different publisher's apps will have different device ID's.