# UniqueDeviceID different between apps on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, uniqueidentifier

We have two apps we've developed for Windows Phone 8. I've set the Publisher ID in the WMAppManifest to be the same GUID, but for some reason each App is declaring it's own UDID.

Why? What have I missed?

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367492/windows-phone-8-find-out-imei-device-name-manufacturer) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975315/get-unique-device-id-udid-under-windows-phone-8) but they don't seem to say anything more.

Each app communicates over a web-service and requires the device identifier, it would be really annoying if each of the 500-odd devices our company has purchased had two rows in the central database.

Any clues anyone?

Comment: Just to make matters more interesting, I've just built the first App (coded by someone else) on my own machine as they are away and we needed to make a quick change. The DeviceUniqueID is now coming up the same... I now need to see if there's something about the build platform that is influencing the generation of this signature. i.e. if I build it on her machine does it generate a different DUID than if I build it on my machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this was a conscious decision by Microsoft "[in order to protect user privacy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431.aspx)". Therefore I don't think it's possible via another API.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit annoying. Just wish I could get to the bottom of what the pattern is.